# specify the variable type in the prompt

Tags: javascript

Instead of the number addition this code is doing the string concatation.
How to specify the type of the input in the prompt field(eg:number,string).

```
var jonage = prompt("enter the johns age");
var jonHeight = prompt("enter the johns height");
var jonScore = jonHeight + jonage * 5;
console.log(jonScore);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prompt` is extremely basic and offers no way to constrain the input other than the way browsers do by default (e.g., no line breaks).

Instead, convert the string to number afterward. There are a lot of ways to do that:

- Unary `+`: `var jonage = +prompt("enter the johns age");`
- `Number`: `var jonage = Number(prompt("enter the johns age"));`
- `parseInt`: `var jonage = parseInt(prompt("enter the johns age"));`
- `parseFloat`: `var jonage = parseFloat(prompt("enter the johns age"));`

#### Unary `+` and `Number`:

...work the same way:

- They convert the entire string to number if possible, yielding `NaN` if the entire string can't be converted to number. So `+"123abc"` is `NaN`.
- They convert an empty string (`""`) to `0` (surprisingly).
- They respect JavaScript syntax for specifying the number base (radix), so `+"0x10"` is 16 and `+"0o10"` is `8`.

#### `parseInt`

- Converts only as much of the string as it can before the first invalid character, not the whole string. So `parstInt("123abc")` is `123`.
- Converts an empty string (`""`) to `NaN` (not `0`).
- Respects JavaScript syntax for specifying the number base (radix), e.g., `parseInt("0x10")` is 16.
- **Also** lets you specify the radix explicitly as a second argument, to force it to treat the input as being in that number base: `parseInt("0x10", 10)` is `0` (because the `x` becomes invalid, `0x` is no longer treated as indicating the number base. This **used** to be important with decimal in case end users entered strings like `"010"` and browsers implemented "legacy" Octal (leading `0` instead of leading `0o`), but it's been eight years now (since the [5th edition spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-E)) since `parseInt` was officially **not** allowed to do that.
- As the name suggests, only converts the part of the string that defines a *whole* number (integer).

#### `parseFloat`

Like `parseInt`, but does fractional numbers and doesn't do radix prefixes. `parseFloat("0x16")` is `0`, because the `x` is invalid (because it doesn't do radix prefixes).

Comment: Always include a radix with `parseInt`: `parseInt(value, 10)`

Comment: @Cerbrus: Meh, it's been eight years since legacy octal was disallowed in `parseInt`. :-)

Comment: Has it been that long? Looking at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Browser_compatibility), it seems there are no supported browsers left that require the radix, indeed...

Comment: @Cerbrus: Wow, I didn't realize IE9 got it right. Nice!

Comment: Yea, that was surprising :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `prompt` will always return a string.

Instead, convert the string to whatever format you want (e.g. with `parseFloat`).

Answer (score 0):

The prompt is always returning it's input as a [String value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp).

You need to parse it to either number (if decimal used) or integer if full numbers used:

**Decimal example**

```
var jonage = Number(prompt("enter the johns age"));
var jonHeight = Number(prompt("enter the johns height"));
var jonScore = jonHeight + jonage * 5;
console.log(jonScore);
```

**Integer example**

```
var jonage = parseInt(prompt("enter the johns age"));
var jonHeight = parseInt(prompt("enter the johns height"));
var jonScore = jonHeight + jonage * 5;
console.log(jonScore);
```

Comment: Always include a radix with `parseInt`: `parseInt(value, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, you cannot change the what the type for the prompt return. It will always return a string. Instead, convert the string into an integer before outputting the result.

Also, it seems like your math logic is wrong? If you want the addition first, then place it in parenthesis before doing the product. Remember that `*` and `/` are executed before `+` and `-`.

```js
var jonage = prompt("enter the johns age");
var jonHeight = prompt("enter the johns height");
var jonScore = (parseInt(jonHeight) + parseInt(jonage)) * 5;
console.log(jonScore);
```

Comment: Always include a radix with `parseInt`: `parseInt(value, 10)`

Comment: @Cerbrus, hmm isn't that default 10?

Comment: Only on modern, up-to-date browsers.

Comment: @Cerbrus No body works for IE 6, 7 or similar older version I guess.

Comment: @Manzurul: IE 8 requires it. Small group, but still.

Comment: @Cerbrus, those people *deserve* it though, muahah Ψ(`_´ )↝

Comment: Fair enough! :D

Answer (score -1):

You always need to convert prompt value as it always a string.

```
var jonage = prompt("enter the johns age");
var jonHeight = prompt("enter the johns height");
var jonScore = parseInt(jonHeight) + parseInt(jonage) * 5;
console.log(jonScore);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZ Yeah I understood that just after posted the answer.

Comment: (And for the record, I was not the one who downvoted you)

Comment: Always include a radix with `parseInt`: `parseInt(value, 10)`

Comment: @Cerbrus I hope you got your answer from above.