# Subtraction operator work but Addition operator not working

Tags: javascript

I has been view some topic about Operator Not Working, but cannot solve my problem.

I have 2 JavaScript code.

```
<span id="number">this work</span>
<span id="miaonumber">this doesn't work</span>
<script>
    setTimeout(start, 1000);

    var hh = 9999.9999;
    var num = document.getElementById('number');

    function start() {
        setInterval(increase, 1000);
        }

    function increase() {
        if (hh > 0.0001) {
            hh = (hh-0.0001).toFixed(15);
            num.innerText = hh;
        }
    }

    setTimeout(startmiao, 1000);

    var zz = 8888.8888;
    var nummiao = document.getElementById('miaonumber');

    function startmiao() {
        setInterval(increasemiao, 1000);
    }

    function increasemiao() {
        if (zz > 0) {
            zz = (zz+0.0001).toFixed(15);
            nummiao.innerText = zz;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The `<span id="number"></span>` will work, but the `<span id="miaonumber"></span>` doesn't work, I open F12 to view, every second +1 error `Uncaught TypeError: (zz + 0.0001).toFixed is not a function`

Comment: If you use `+` with a string and a number, the result is a string, not a number. Strings don't have `toFixed`. You'll need to ensure that `zz` is a number (it isn't once you've assigned the result of `toFixed` to it), [in any of the many ways you can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48227674/157247).

Comment: I would also describe the fact that using subtraction coerces the value to a number, whereas addition (concatenation) doesn't. That is why the first version works and the second doesn't. Neither of the current answers mention this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're converting both hh and zz to strings when you use `.toFixed()`.  If you keep them as numbers then they both work.  Simply move the `.toFixed()` to where you set the element text.

```js
setTimeout(start, 1000);

var hh = 9999.9999;
var num = document.getElementById('number');

function start() {
    setInterval(increase, 1000);
    }

function increase() {
    if (hh > 0.0001) {
        hh = hh - 0.0001;
        num.innerText = hh.toFixed(15);
    }
}

setTimeout(startmiao, 1000);

var zz = 8888.8888;
var nummiao = document.getElementById('miaonumber');

function startmiao() {
    setInterval(increasemiao, 1000);
}

function increasemiao() {
    if (zz > 0) {
        zz = zz + 0.0001;
        nummiao.innerText = zz.toFixed(15);
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="number">this work</span><br />
<span id="miaonumber">this doesn't work</span>
```

Javascript is sensible enough to know that when you subtract values it's most likely that you want them to be numbers, so `"123" - 1 == 122`, but when you try to add it assumes you want to append to an existing string, so `"123" + 1 == "1231"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you have a number and convert it to a string and the you assign it to `zz` again. Then you add a number, but while `zz` is a string, you get a string and string does not has the method `toString`.

Solution: Assign the stringed value only to the output and not to `zz`.

```js
function start() {
    setInterval(increase, 1000);
}

function increase() {
    if (hh > 0.0001) {
        hh = (hh - 0.0001).toFixed(15);
        num.innerText = hh;
    }
}

function startmiao() {
    setInterval(increasemiao, 1000);
}

function increasemiao() {
    if (zz > 0) {
        zz += 0.0001;
        nummiao.innerText = zz.toFixed(15);
    }
}

var hh = 9999.9999,
    num = document.getElementById('number'),
    zz = 8888.8888,
    nummiao = document.getElementById('miaonumber');

setTimeout(start, 1000);
setTimeout(startmiao, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="number">this work</span>
<span id="miaonumber">this doesn't work</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`toFixed` obtains a string value from a numeric value. When you then attempt to use `+` with this string value it defaults to concatenating text, rather than addition. This new text no longer has a `toFixed` method.

Use `toFixed` only when displaying the value(s), so that `zz` remains a number:

```
function increasemiao() {
    if (zz > 0) {
        zz = (zz+0.0001);
        nummiao.innerText = zz.toFixed(15);
    }
}
```

(This is also why it works initially, with 8888.8889, but fails on subsequent iterations.)

The first version works because subtraction (rather than addition/concatenation) coerces a value to a number.